# Only one List item displayed when changing screen / page

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-hive

On the *add Weight* screen I pick a weight and a date and then it gets stored in a list in the Hive database, once I press "Save".
It also returns me to the Homepage, where I would like to depict the stored list items in a `ListView.Builder`.
I only get the last item on the list and not the whole list.
When I am at the *add weight* screen, I see that there are more items in the list, but once I return to homepage only the last one exists.

*AddWeightScreen*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:weighty/components/my_alert_box.dart';
import 'package:weighty/data/database.dart';
import 'package:weighty/screens/home_page.dart';

class AddWeight extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddWeight({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddWeight> createState() => _AddWeightState();
}

class _AddWeightState extends State<AddWeight> {
  Database db = Database();
  final _myBox = Hive.box("mybox");
  double _currentValue = 0;
  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(DateTime.now());
  final _weightController = TextEditingController();

  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = value!;
        formattedDate = DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(_dateTime);
      });
    });
  }

// add weight from text -  keyboard
  void _dialogNumber() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return MyAlertBox(
              controller: _weightController,
              hintText: "Enter today's weight...",
              onSave: () {
                if (double.parse(_weightController.text) > 200) {
                  _weightController.text = "200";
                }
                setState(() {
                  _currentValue = double.parse(_weightController.text);
                });

                _weightController.clear();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              onCancel: cancelDialogBox);
        });
  }

  //save method
  void _saveWeightAndDate() {
    setState(() {
      db.weightList.add([_currentValue, formattedDate]);
    });
    db.saveData();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  // cancel new weight input
  void cancelDialogBox() {
    // clear textfield
    _weightController.clear();

    // pop dialog box
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD9F0FF),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 28.0,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Add Weight",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'CANCEL',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff878472),
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _dialogNumber,
                      child: Text(
                        _currentValue.toStringAsFixed(2) + " kg",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
                            fontSize: 46,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Slider(
                    value: _currentValue,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 200,
                    onChanged: ((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentValue = value;
                      });
                    }),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: _showDatePicker,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.date_range_outlined,
                      size: 24.0,
                      color: Color(0xff878472),
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      formattedDate,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff878472), fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _saveWeightAndDate,
                    child: Text(
                      'SAVE',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      elevation: 24,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 80),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*HomePage*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:weighty/components/weight_tile.dart';
import 'package:weighty/data/database.dart';
import 'package:weighty/main.dart';
import 'package:weighty/screens/add_weight.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    //First time ever opening app, Create default data
    // if (_myBox.get("WEIGHTLIST") == null) {

    // }

    //already exists data

    db.loadData();

    // db.saveData();

    super.initState();
  }

  Database db = Database();
  final _myBox = Hive.box("mybox");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff006B8F),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const AddWeight(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 28),
            Text(
              "CURRENT",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              db.weightList.length == 0
                  ? "00.0 Kg"
                  : db.weightList.last[0].toStringAsFixed(2) + " kg",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
                fontSize: 46.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                "GRAPH",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: db.weightList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return WeightTile(
                    date: db.weightList[index][1],
                    weight: db.weightList[index][0].toStringAsFixed(2),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(db.weightList.length);
                },
                child: Text('Print!')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Hive Database*

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class Database {
  //reference the box
  final _myBox = Hive.box("mybox");

  // Empty Weight List
  List weightList = [];

  // void createInitialData() {
  //   weightList = [];
  // }

  //load the date from the db
  void loadData() {
    weightList = _myBox.get("WEIGHTLIST");
  }

  //save the weight

  void saveData() {
    _myBox.put("WEIGHTLIST", weightList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whole list you have to first get old list which is saved in hive then sum this list and save in to hive
Output is

For you example you have to update `saveData`  method in to a `Database` class

```
 void saveData() {
    final myBox = Hive.box("mybox");

    List? hiveList = [];
    hiveList = myBox.get("WEIGHTLIST") ?? [];
    if (hiveList!.isNotEmpty) {
      hiveList += weightList;
    } else {
      hiveList = weightList;
    }
_myBox.put("WEIGHTLIST", hiveList);
```

}

You will be get whole list into a homescreen

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I implement your code I get this error: ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Database.saveData
package:weighty/data/database.dart:28
#1      _AddWeightState._saveWeightAndDate

Comment: @Biobrolly please uninstall older app and install again

Comment: @Biobrolly are you getting your issue?

Comment: Sadly, I get the same error. This happens when I press on the Save button on the AddWeight Screen.

Comment: After uninstall and installing then the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the app from the phone and re installed it. I will try flutter clean now.

Comment: @Biobrolly okay then let me know ...if its still not working

Comment: Same error, sadly. Maybe it has to do with the initial loading of the List on the Homepage in the initState?

Comment: After press the save button right?

Comment: Are getting error on - save button elase where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251030/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-biobrolly).

Answer (score 2):

I could not rebuild your project to debug it. so I'm kind of taking a shot in the darkness.
there is a widget called valuelistenablebuilder which gets rebuilt when ever a value changes you can set your box to the value being listened by this widget and rebuild every time a new value is added to your box you can find an example on [this page](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Comment: I Tried your approach but for some reason I could not get it to work.

Comment: well if you'd like we can discuss it some more and try to fix it.